# Difference between "copy" and "copy qualified name"

Tags: eclipse

I know it is very basic and maybe because it is so basic that I can't find an answer. What is the difference between "copy" and "copy qualified name" in eclipse? Thank you.

Comment: Do both and paste the result, and you'll know.

Answer (score 4):

"Copy" will literally copy the object you have selected and "Copy Qualified Name" will copy the name of the object including the package or path information of the element you are coping.

I often select a class name in the java editor and use Copy Qualified Name to get the fully qualified class name. For example selecting "Object" and using Copy would just copy the literal text "Object" but copy fully qualified name would result in "java.lang.Object"

You can also use it with files and directories in the Package Explorer or Project Explorer. In this case Copy will just copy the file and Copy Qualified Name will copy the path to the file including the directories leading up to the file.